# Multiple regression with few observations and many variables

Tags: multiple-regression, small-sample, stepwise-regression

I have data about 40 stores described by 50+ continuous variables in terms of customer behaviour (types of purchases, demographic attributes, etc). I want to build a simple **regression model** to explain the profitability of stores based on what we know about the rest. So I:

1. Removed variables with many missing values
2. Removed co-variates above a certain correlation threshold (for example rho > .7)

I still have a lot of variables (18) that might have a decent explanatory power. I read that **stepwise regression** is [a terrible idea](https://journalofbigdata.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40537-018-0143-6), but I'm not sure what better method I could apply in this context, considering the very small number of observations that makes cross-validation approaches hard.

Any sound alternative to both linear regression and stepwise selection methods?

Comment: Using theory to guide your model building and reporting (including negative findings) is the sound alternative you are looking for because stepwise model building is [indeed a terrible idea](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/338804/hypothesis-testing-on-coefficients-in-two-subsets-of-data-after-stepwise-regress/338807#338807).

Comment: "Removed co-variates above a certain correlation threshold (for example rho > .7)" Correlation with what? Why?

Comment: In a situation like this, I think that forward selection isn't that terrible, maybe using the AIC rather than significance testing. I'm not saying it's the best you can do (Lasso may well be better), but if I were you I'd well may run it at least for curiosity reasons. And with $n=40$  you actually can do leave-one-out CV to compare models (like those resulting from different dimension reduction approaches).

Comment: if you want a fancy alternative to stepwise regression, you could try folded concave penalized regression, like that implemented in Spike-Slab Lasso's R package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SSLASSO/index.html

Comment: What's the goal of this analysis, ie, what do you mean by "explain profitability"? (And you could also use regularization depending on why you are building a model.)

Comment: I removed co-variates because I guess that's a generally good idea in any model. The model has the purpose to capture what factors drive profitability.

Answer (score 1):

A thing to think about is whether you can use subject matter knowledge to define a small number of meaningful indexes summarising your original variables, and then build a model on them.

Comment: Something like PCA but simply combining the variables? Interesting suggestion

Comment: @Strabonio In fact my proposal can be seen as "something like PCA", but PCA does such a thing in an automatic data driven manner, which will give you something harder to make sense of in an application like this. Also PCA does not take into account the $y$ and so PCs may not work well for predicting $y$, and if you use subject matter knowledge for defining indexes, you may well arrive at something better (although this depends on the knowledge you have and cannot be taken for granted).

Comment: @Strabonio Note that *not* taking into account the $y$ when doing dimension reduction has the advantage that the regression later carried out on the resulting variables will not suffer from model selection bias.